# Jquery blinking trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a following html structure:

```
<a class='support'>Podpořit</a>
<div class='fa'>
    <a id='1' href='drak1 (1).jpg' class='fa-envelope mail-voting'></a>
    <a id='1' href='drak1 (1).jpg' class='fa-facebook facebook-voting'></a>
</div>
```

And this is my javascript code:

```
 $(".support").mouseover(function() {
        activeButton = $(this).next();
        activeButton.show();
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $(".support").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).show();
        $(this).next().hide();
    });
```

I want to show the .fa div on .support hover and if I leave the area, I want to show .support back again. How can I do it? Now it's blinking :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".support").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).children("div").show();
    $(this).children("a").hide();
  });

  $(".support").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children("div.fa").hide();
    $(this).children("a").show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="support">
  <a>Podpořit</a> 
  <div class='fa' style="display:none">
    <a id='1' href='drak1 (1).jpg' class='fa-envelope mail-voting'>Random content</a>
    <a id='1' href='drak1 (1).jpg' class='fa-facebook facebook-voting'>Random content</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added a container because you can't put a mouseleave event on an element you are hiding, because it will trigger as fast as it hides.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a div and do like this,

```
 $(".containerDiv").mouseover(function() {
        activeButton = $(this).next();
        activeButton.show();
        $(this).find(".support").hide();
    });

    $(".containerDiv").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find(".support").show();
        $(this).next().hide();
    });
```

In your code your are hiding the element itself which in turn cause the mouse leave event to trigger.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/84/)